# How to change colors of individual bars based on some property in Timeline Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-google-charts

I am using this [Google Timeline Component](https://www.react-google-charts.com/examples/timeline). I need to use colors based on the one of the column property is there a way to do that? I want all bars with one property to have same color not different.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
export const options = {
  title: "Company Performance",
  curveType: "function",
  legend: { position: "bottom" },
  colors:["green"]
};
```

change the color key to have different colors

Comment: This is setting colors of all of them to green. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/RakanNimer/react-google-charts/tree/master/sandboxes/timeline/advanced?from-embed=&file=/App.tsx) I want colors of people with particular name to have a same color.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create arrays to define bar color for each different property.
2. When you define the data, you can use the role property to define a color of bar.
   https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole
   const data = [ [ { type: "string", id: "Phases" }, { type: "string", id: "Name" }, { type: 'string', role: 'style' }, { type: "date", id: "Start" },         { type: "date", id: "End" } ]];
3. Finally, you concat the arrays in Chart data.
   data={[...data, ...firstArray, ...secondArray]}

This is my first answer in stackoverflow. I hope I helped you.